# Matching edges in 2 graphs

Tags: r, igraph

I have 2 graphs, lets call them g1 and g2. The graph g2 has the same structure as g1 but contains new edges that are not present in g1. I have to find these edges.

```
g1 <- graph(edges=c(1,2,2,3,1,3,3,4,2,4,1,5), n=5, directed=FALSE)
g2 <- graph(edges=c(1,2,2,3,1,3,3,4,2,4,1,5,3,5), n=5, directed=FALSE)
```

In this case what i'm looking for is the edge 3--5.

So far i thought of using the complementer of g1 then matching it with the edges from g2 to find these new edges. The problem is that i'm having trouble with the syntax. (new to R)

```
g1_complement <- complementer(g1)
```

Now i'd like to get only the new edges that are in g2 but NOT in g1. I was thinking of doing this.

```
E(g1_complement)[E(g1_complement) %in% E(g2)]
```

I was expecting to get only the new edges, but this returns all the g1_complement edges. I am only using igraph as library.

Comment: Could you provide your graphs?   Try using `dput(g1)` and `dput(g2)` and pasting the results in your question.

Comment: @G5W The graphs i'm using are way bigger and therefore can't post them, but i provided a smaller version of what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find below one possible solution using the `difference()` function from the `igraph` library.

**Reprex**

```r
library(igraph)

g1 <- graph(edges=c(1,2,2,3,1,3,3,4,2,4,1,5), n=5, directed=FALSE)
g2 <- graph(edges=c(1,2,2,3,1,3,3,4,2,4,1,5,3,5), n=5, directed=FALSE)


difference(g2, g1)
#> IGRAPH 9fb5e8c U--- 5 1 -- 
#> + edge from 9fb5e8c:
#> [1] 3--5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
> E(g2)[!E(g2) %in% E(g1)]
+ 1/7 edge from 9fdc2d2:
[1] 3--5

> E(g2)[setdiff(E(g2), E(g1))]
+ 1/7 edge from 9fdc2d2:
[1] 3--5
```

Comment: This only works because the example put the edge we're looking for last. Try it with `g2 <- graph(edges=c(3,5,1,2,2,3,1,3,3,4,2,4,1,5), n=5, directed=FALSE)`